# How to run a web app using sbcl+restas+apache?

Tags: apache, web, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Recently I get a work to write a web app with others. They have chosen to use Apache, so I have to use it. But I was writing my program in `sbcl` using restas. So I got confused how to run my app behind Apache. I have tried the `mod_lisp`, but it seems unuseful. All I get is a page saying `:Internal Server Error.`

When I check the apache error log, I find:

```
[core:error] [pid 18294:tid 140614142228224] [client 127.0.0.1:44049] AH00135: Invalid method in request server-protocol

[:error] [pid 18295:tid 140614150620928] (70014)End of file found: error reading from Lisp
```

Now I get confused more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure [Apache to act as a reverse-proxy](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies). Personally, I prefer [`nginx`](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/), but whatever works for you.

The idea is that you'd be running your SBCL listening to some local port, waiting for requests to be piped in from Apache. Apache would be taking requests directly from clients, and passing some of them to your web application (presumably, you'd want the external server to handle static assets for you).